# Select list of x via list of y

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Here's the DB setup of 3 tables:

```
Template
-----------
TemplateId (Pk Identity)
Name

Example Data:

TemplateId  Name
1           Homepage
2           Generic Landing Page


TemplateArea (Bridge table to keep track of each template type's list of areas)
----------------
TemplateAreaId (Pk Identity)
TemplateId (Fk)
AreaId (Fk)

Example Data:

    TemplateAreaId   TemplateId   AreaId
    1                1            1
    2                1            2
    3                1            3
    4                2            1
    5                2            2
```

So every template has 3 areas (you're seeing a set of templateIds (e.g. 2) and related set of AreaIds (1 & 2))

```
Area
-----
AreaId (Pk Name)
Name

Example Data:

    AreaId  Name
    1       Top
    2       Middle
    3       Bottom
```

I'm trying to get a list of Areas based on a list of TemplateAreas keyed off of AreaId in my list of TemplateAreas:

so for example I should get this list of content areas for a TemplateId 2:

```
AreaId  Name
1       Top
2       Middle


int templateId = 2;

List<TemplateArea> templateAreas = TemplateAreas.Where(ta => ta.TemplateId == templateId).ToList();

List<Area> areas = Areas.Where()); // this is where I'm stuck, how to get the list of areas (1 & 2) relatd to templateId 2
```

so in other words, get a list of Template Areas then get a list of related Areas keyed off of the specific TemplateId.

I'm basically trying to join to TemplateArea from Area on TemplateArea.TemplateId = templateId or something like that if this were T-SQL, e.g. Something like:

select AreaId, Name from Area join TemplateArea on Area.AreaId = TemplateArea.AreaId where TemplateArea.TemplateId = templateId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code approach as a guide, you can join to the templateAreas:

```
List<Area> areas = Area.Join(templateAreas, a => a.AreaId, t => t.AreaId, (a, t) => a);
```

Comment: so your query is giving back a list of Areas based on a join to TemplateAreas where TemplateAreas.TemplateId = 2?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Yes, the result set in this case will only contain Area 1 & 2

Comment: Yea thanks, I see now.  The a => a.AreaId, t => t.AreaId is really the join ON key basically as t is representing my templateAreas List<TemplateArea>.  Thanks.!

Comment: err, I'm getting the compile error Error on the join:  'System.Linq.Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TInner,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Here is the working sample code I tested the answer with: https://gist.github.com/1683078

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
List<Area> areas = TemplateAreas.Where(ta => ta.TemplateId == templateId).Select(ta => ta.Areas).Distinct().ToList();
```

I am pretty sure this would work in Entity Framework, just not sure in Linq to Sql.

Comment: I don't get how this TemplateAreas.Where is returning a list of Type Area...there's no reference to how TemplateAreas is returning a totally different type here which is type Area..so I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
List<Area> areas = Areas.Where(ta => ta.TemplateId == templateId).Select(ta => ta.Areas).ToList();
```

you can access any of the area field using this..